What did non-Earth societies know about the cause of and motivation for the Snap?
On Earth, where the Snap happened, who did it and why was apparently widely known, presumably because the remaining Avengers explained (evidence - the graffiti in the Hawkeye series saying "Thanos was right" - indicating that the writer knew the name of the perpetrator and had some idea of his motive/goal).
But all other planets with life were also affected. Did Thanos, his agents, or Captain Marvel explain what happened to non-Earth societies, or did those societies have a devastating, terrifying loss, with no explanation at all? (that would be an interesting story).

I found the prevalence of that sentiment not very believable worldbuilding. In the real world, there are people selfish enough to dismiss genocides or even support them if they are not personally affected or benefit. But the nature of what Thanos did was such that, for instance, even someone who got a promotion or was able to immigrate to another country almost certainly lost at least several friends or family members, if not dozens. Ignoring what surely should have been widespread chaos among the survivors.

So no matter whether someone's financial situation or safety incidentally improved, only the most abject sociopaths devoid of human connection would likely feel that they were personally better off. It feels like a kind of careless import of a real-world joke meme to a setting where it would be as marginal as saying eating babies is actually an essential part of a balanced diet. Basically, look at how many surviving Jews in Nazi Germany were fans of the Holocaust, or how popular King Leopold was among survivors in the Belgian Congo: that's going to be the whole world.

@Andrew - Are you asking about non-Earth societies across the entire universe, or just those in the Milky Way galaxy? It's probably safe to say that most societies in galaxies other than the Milky Way were mystified as to the cause of the deaths, given that the likes of Thanos and Captain Marvel were not shown to communicate with life in other galaxies.

I'll take info about any nonEarth society

"a large number of other planets were also affected" - Indeed, all planets with life were affected.

I clarified the question (I hope)

AFAIK, the only reference to other worlds is when Carol says "The
things that have been happening on
Earth have been happening
everywhere else." - Whether she communicated what/why happened is unknown so far.

I believe this is another example of the trope "sci-fi authors don't understand the size of the universe". The Milky Way is so tiny compared to the universe. Thanos cannot know anything about the universe at large to make any informed decision about whether the Snap was right; so I figure most sentient lifeforms were mystified and also Thanos (or anyone in the known MCU) didn't even know they existed.

@AndresF. He's also got a bunch of magic rocks capable of rearranging the universe, presumably they can do data collection, but perhaps showing the check and confirmation that even intelligent life expands until checked by available resources is a universal trope, with the milky way proving to be a typical example would be a bit dry for the big screen.

@Jontia but that's just another example of the trope, isn't it? A lifetime wouldn't be enough for Thanos to process any data collection about life on the universe, or collect it for that matter. Thanos simply cannot draw any conclusions about life in the universe because he has only seen a tiny fraction of it. If the answer is "magic", then anything goes, and the question itself becomes void. But yeah, maybe the magic rocks told him "destroooooy... detroooooy 'em all!" ;)
